# Oracle APEX - An unexpected error with the following message occurred: application&#x2F;pdf

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, jasper-reports

I have a pl/sql procedure that that downloads a blob file in pdf format from Jasper Server. In this procedure I have the following code which prompts the browser to download the file to my local drive.

```
begin
    v_param_val (1) := 1;
    owa.init_cgi_env (v_param_val);

    htp.flush;
    -- clear the output buffer and reset response state
    htp.init;

    owa_util.mime_header ('application/pdf', false);--,'UTF-8'
    htp.p('Content-length: ' || v_lob_length);
    htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'||v_file||'"' );
    owa_util.http_header_close;

    htp.showpage ();
    wpg_docload.download_file(v_blobref);

exception
    when timeout_on_resource then
        raise_application_error (-00051,'No response from the server.');  
    when others then
        htp.p('other error : ' || sqlerrm);
end;
```

The problem is, I have an oracle apex page that I use to call my procedure. The page passes through the values to be used as parameters in the call of the procedure. I have a an apex process that makes this happen...

```
declare
    v_report_name reports_data.report_name%type;

begin   
    v_report_name := s_reports_data.get_report_name(:P31_AVAILABLE_REPORTS);

    s_reports_data.generate_jasper_report(v_report_name, :P31_DATE_TO, 
    :P31_RESEARCH_STATION, :P31_DATE_FROM);
end;
```

No the following error comes up when I try to call the procedure.

> An unexpected error with the following message occurred: application/pdf

It seems like the following line is the cause of the error.

```
owa_util.mime_header ('application/pdf', false);--,'UTF-8'
```

Or the following line.

```
wpg_docload.download_file(v_blobref);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/w_util.htm#i997447), the function seems to need 3 parameters. Have you tried

```
owa_util.mime_header('application/pdf', false, 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: Hi tobi6, yes I did try this and it gives me the same error. 500 Internal Server Error

An unexpected error with the following message occurred: application&#x2F;pdf; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Then the response might not be setup correctly and it is not expected that headers will come. Did this setup work earlier?

Comment: Initially I was writing to the pdf file and saving to a directory and it worked fine, then I manipulated the code to prompt and save to my local drive...and that's when I had to use owa_util and bumped into this error.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got rid of the problem I had. This is how my code looks like now and it works perfectly fine.

```
begin
  sys.htp.init;    
  sys.owa_util.mime_header (nvl(v_mime,'application/octet'), false, 'UTF-8');
  sys.htp.p('Content-length: ' || v_lob_length);
  sys.htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="'||v_file||'"' );
  sys.owa_util.http_header_close;

  sys.wpg_docload.download_file(v_blobref);
  apex_application.stop_apex_engine;

exception when others then
  sys.htp.prn('error: '||sqlerrm);
  apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
end;
```